# Determining the hubs in a small-world graph

Tags: graph-theory, network

How can you determine the "hub" nodes in a small-world graph especially when the degree distribution is fairly symmetric? I imagine what constitutes a hub or not is fairly arbitrary, or is there some criterion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These metrics are called 'centralities' in network theory. The one most likely to be useful to you is [betweenness centrality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness_centrality). The betweenness centrality of a node is the proportion of all shortest path lengths in the graph that go through that node.

Comment: Thanks, and just to follow up - how can a small-world graph have a fairly symmetric degree distribution? That seems to eliminate the possibility of hubs, or not?

Comment: @user2561523 No, it doesn't necessarily eliminate hubs. You can even have a regular graph with hubs - see https://www.researchgate.net/figure/3-regular-graph-with-girth-4-which-is-a-counterexample-showing-that-M-3-3-3_fig1_220533348. You can't get more symmetric of a degree distribution than that, but the central node is clearly a hub!